# How to set default props to required props in functional components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

In Typescript, I set up a component as follows:

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  type: 'round' | 'square';
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({type = 'round'}) => {
  return (
    <div />
  );
};
```

The `type` prop is required and has a default set in the component definition, but still I get and error when calling the component:

```js
<MyComponent />
// Property 'type' is missing in type '{ }' but required in type 'MyComponentProps'.
```

Setting the property `type` to an optional `type?` solves the problem by implicitly changing the type to `'round' | 'square' | undefined` but I don't want the property to be possibly `undefined`, because that would cause issues and weird code down the line where I must consider `type` being `undefined` at every point.

## What do I want to happen?

I want 'type' to have a default value when not passed, but not be defined as `undefined` (i.e. optional).

## What have I tried?

I tried adding

```
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  type: 'round'
};
```

But this didn't help at all, and also I know that `defaultProps` are about to become deprecated for functional components anyway.

Comment: If you want a default value then that will not be a required prop right?

Comment: Technically yes, but a "non-required" prop suggests it's optional, which means it could be undefined, which I don't want to happen, since then I must assert it is defined at every step.

Comment: Then default props works right ?

Comment: If the prop is optional and not passed then the default prop takes over, so it works in that sense. If the prop is required, has a default, but not passed then the app won't even compile. defining `defaultProps` has no effect at all.

Comment: This doesn’t support in that way. As you provide the default prop. This will not be a required prop. If you want that prop as other value you have to pass that value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass default value that means value is not mandatory. if value will not come then you have default value.

Answer (score 0):

### Update for `typescript@4.4`

Since `ts@4.4` you can define such a type without explicit type assertion when [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) flag is set:

```ts
type MyComponentProps = {
  type: 'round' | 'square';
} | {
  type?: never
}

const MyComponent = ({type = 'round'}: MyComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <div />
  );
}

const NoProps = <MyComponent />
const UndefProp = <MyComponent type={undefined} /> // error
const WithProp = <MyComponent type="round" />
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAVn1W)

Unfortunatelly TS playground does not support storing `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag in the url yet. So you'll have to go into `TS Config` and set it manually.

---

I believe you cannot get what you want with straighforward typescript features. But massaging your types a bit with type assertion you can get pretty close:

```ts
interface MyComponentProps {
  type: 'round' | 'square';
}

const MyComponent = (({type = 'round'}: MyComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <div />
  );
}) as React.FC<MyComponentProps | {}>

const NoProps = <MyComponent />
const UndefProp = <MyComponent type={undefined} /> // error
const WithProp = <MyComponent type="round" />
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEDzVW)

Comment: I don't know how this works in your playground, but as soon as I add the `| {}` bit all the props in my IDE lose their type and omit errors, claiming `type` doesn't exist in this interface.

Comment: Can you copy your exacty code with the errors to the TS playground?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try followings this:

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  type?: 'round' | 'square';
}

const defaultProps: MyComponentProps = {
  type: 'round'
};

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({type}) => {
  return (
    <div />
  );
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```